# Как проверить является ли файл каталогом?

Tags: reactjs

Вот вызывается метод onDrop, в acceptedFiles данные такие

```
   onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
   acceptedFiles[0];
}
```

Это папка node-v10.10.0-linux-x64.

```
: File(4096)
lastModified: 1536267161000
lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 06 2018 23:52:41 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) {}
name: "node-v10.10.0-linux-x64"
preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/063c7af6-8d30-450e-b038-fff24ba51902"
size: 4096
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

А это файл account.bson

```
 File(0)
lastModified: 1536313052000
lastModifiedDate: Fri Sep 07 2018 12:37:32 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) {}
name: "account.bson"
preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/29894f82-0ea4-4f7c-9ad9-538e724cda4e"
size: 0
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

Comment: А DropZone позволяет выбрать каталог? У меня не вышло

Comment: Позволяет, если перемещать каталог в зону сброса. У меня ubuntu

Comment: Хм... действительно

Comment: Тогда наверное никак. Класс File не содержит каких-либо свойств на эту тему

Comment: @DmitryKozlov оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ